# What is true about Delegates in c# (should be match signature with functions or not)?

Tags: c#, delegates

Today I am doing study about delegates. I read that delegate's signature and method signature should be match exactly.

I read this from this website

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/09/C-Sharp-delegates-example-use-of-delegates-in-C-Sharp.html

But when I go to MSDN then i read this statement there

Methods do not have to match the delegate signature exactly. For more information, see Using Variance in Delegates (C# and Visual Basic).

Here is the link for this article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Now i am confused Please tell me which is true about delegates and both the articles are updated

Comment: Any reason to doubt MSDN? It is the *official* documentation after all

Comment: No actually the other article i read is also latest article that is why i am confused please tell me in detail about delegates

Comment: Then the other article is wrong, and that's not its only problem. Just because it was written recently doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: ok sir then u saying that there is no  restrictions regarding signatures with delegates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [MSDN documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it's about **covariance** and **contravariance**.

One of the example on MSDN is pretty clear, read the code comments:

```
// Event hander that accepts a parameter of the EventArgs type. 
private void MultiHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // You can use a method that has an EventArgs parameter, 
    // although the event expects the KeyEventArgs parameter. 
    this.button1.KeyDown += this.MultiHandler;

    // You can use the same method  
    // for an event that expects the MouseEventArgs parameter. 
    this.button1.MouseClick += this.MultiHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have really good reason not to trust what Microsoft says about its own creation, I'd suggest trusting the MSDN article over what an enthusiast says on their blog.